# PDO elimina duplicidade de campos da SQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Bom galera, estou usando PDO para executar minhas `querys`.

SQL:

```
SELECT Pessoa.IdPessoa, Pessoa.IdPessoa, Pessoa.Nome AS 'Nome', Pessoa.DataNascimento AS 'Nascimento' FROM Pessoa WHERE Pessoa.EstadoCivil = '1'
```

quando executo essa sql por exemplo, que traz o campo `IdPessoa` duas vezes, o retorno do PDO usando a função

```
$result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Omite um dos resultados e a consulta traz um array, mas apenas com um campo `IdPessoa`

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [IdPessoa] => 7
            [Nome] => Carlos Alberto Martins Barros
            [Nascimento] =>
        )
)
```

tem algo a ser feito, para que o PDO não elimine essa duplicidade?

se usar apenas

```
$result->fetchAll();
```

Vai trazer resultados duplicados, mas serão todos os campos, com índices numéricos e índices com o nome do resultado da `Query`, assim não serviria.

Comment: Coloca [aliases](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) na segunda coluna.

Comment: Estou com um problema parecido, mas não é no select. É o insert é que causa isto, pois a cada registro enviado é duplicado na tabela.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize:

```
$result->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
```

ou

```
$result->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Qualquer dúvida veja esta duas documentações do PHP

[PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

[PDOStatement::fetch](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Esta documentação irá detalhar mais as opções que você tem. Mas acredito que os exemplos acima já serão suficientes.